# Exponential runtime of is/2 when linear would suffice

Tags: prolog

In Prolog building huge trees that are tiny graphs is easy:

```
p(1).
p(X+X) :- p(X).
```

For handling such terms with builtin predicates many Prolog systems offer optimized implementations of `ground/1` but not for `is/2`.

So I wonder:

> 1. Is there a Prolog system that offers an `is/2` implementation which runs in linear time for such terms?
> 2. Is there a particular reason many Prolog systems choose not to offer such an optimized implementation? (something like "it isn't important enough" or "it would slow the general case").

Thank you in advance for your answers and ideas!

Comment: The case systems are optimized for are expression that are present at term-to-body conversions time. The remaining variables are almost always instantiated to numbers only.

Comment: @false. For "an expression"?

Comment: Where is the `is` in the `p/1` example?

Comment: @brebs. It is after the `p/1` call... like so: `?- p(X), V is X.`

Comment: For anything requiring intense calculations with Prolog I would most likely use the foreign language interface. One of favorite such libraries to access is [Theano](https://pypi.org/project/Theano/).

Comment: "Choose not to" implies that there's a known implementation method. Is there?

Comment: Would https://mercurylang.org/ optimize as desired?

Answer (score 0):

Can't this just be restated as:

```
pinc(N, T) :-
    pinc(1, 1, N, T).

pinc(N, T, N, T).
pinc(N0, T0, N, T) :-
    N1 is N0 + N0,
    T1 = T0+T0,
    pinc(N1, T1, N, T).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(pinc(N, T)).
% 1 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (67% CPU, 178891 Lips)
N = T, T = 1 ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (81% CPU, 633312 Lips)
N = 2,
T = 1+1 ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (81% CPU, 342067 Lips)
N = 4,
T = 1+1+(1+1) ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (81% CPU, 325330 Lips)
N = 8,
T = 1+1+(1+1)+(1+1+(1+1)) ;
% 5 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (80% CPU, 583703 Lips)
N = 16,
T = 1+1+(1+1)+(1+1+(1+1))+(1+1+(1+1)+(1+1+(1+1))) ;
```

Comment: Quite witty. But why can't `is/2` to that for me? (Btw. the mechanics behind that could also be usable for resource-limited memoization.)